# Giving priority to prefix match in elasticsearch in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Is there a way in elasticsearch to give more priority for the prefix match than to the string that contains that word?

For ex.- priorities of words if I search for `ram` should be like this:

```
Ram Reddy
Joy Ram Das
Kiran Ram Goel
Swati Ram Goel
Ramesh Singh
```

I have tried mapping as given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532813/correct-sorting-for-exact-matches-and-beginning-with-prefix-in-elasticsearch/54538015#54538015).
I have done like this:

```
$params = [
        "index" => $myIndex,
            "body" => [
            "settings"=> [
            "analysis"=> [
                "analyzer"=> [
                "start_with_analyzer"=> [
                    "tokenizer"=> "my_edge_ngram",
                    "filter"=> [
                    "lowercase"
                    ]
                ]
                ],
                "tokenizer"=> [
                "my_edge_ngram"=> [
                    "type"=> "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram"=> 3,
                    "max_gram"=> 15
                ]
                ]
            ]
            ],
            "mappings"=> [
            "doc"=> [
                "properties"=> [
                "label"=> [
                    "type"=> "text",
                    "fields"=> [
                    "keyword"=> [
                        "type"=> "keyword"
                    ],
                    "ngramed"=> [
                        "type"=> "text",
                        "analyzer"=> "start_with_analyzer"
                    ]
                    ]
                ]
                ]
            ]
            ]
    ]
    ];
    $response = $client->indices()->create($params);    // create an index
```

and searching like this:

```
$body = [
        "size" => 100,

        '_source' => $select,
        "query"=> [
            "bool"=> [
              "should"=> [
                [
                  "query_string"=> [
                    "query"=> "ram*",
                    "fields"=> [
                      "value"
                    ],
                    "boost"=> 5
                  ]
                ],
                [
                  "query_string"=> [
                    "query"=> "ram*",
                    "fields"=> [
                      "value.ngramed"
                    ],
                    "analyzer"=> "start_with_analyzer",
                    "boost"=> 2
                  ]
                ]
              ],
              "minimum_should_match"=> 1
            ]
          ]
    ];

$params = [
    'index' => $myIndex,
    'type' => $myType,
    'body' => []
];
$params['body'] = $body;
$response = $client->search($params);
```

The json of query is as follows:

```
    {
  "size": 100,
  "_source": [
    "label",
    "value",
    "type",
    "sr"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "ram*",
            "fields": [
              "value"
            ],
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "ram*",
            "fields": [
              "value.ngramed"
            ],
            "analyzer": "start_with_analyzer",
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "must_not": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "type": "propertyValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using elasticsearch 5.3.2
Is there any other way to sort the results for the search in the relational database using the search method in php?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NishantSaini I am unable to figure out anything to do this. I have implemented the normal search.

Comment: Please add mapping of the index and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: This answer might give you a starting point.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532813/correct-sorting-for-exact-matches-and-beginning-with-prefix-in-elasticsearch/54538015#54538015

Comment: Thanks @NishantSaini I'll try using it.

Comment: @NishantSaini Can you please tell me how to use mapping in php? Any resource which I can refer?

Comment: You have to use any of the available php client for elaticsearch and use that to create mapping etc.

Comment: @NishantSaini I've tried implementing and have added that to the question. Please help.

Comment: Rather than php code, can you add final json query? Also please add mapping of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not enable `fielddata` unless really required. To overcome this you can use sub field.
Make the following changes to your code:

```
                       "label"=>[
                            "type"=>"text",
                            //"fielddata"=> true, ---->remove/comment this line
                            "analyzer"=>"whitespace",
                            "fields"=>[
                                "keyword"=>[
                                    "type"=>"keyword"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
```

To sort on `type` field use `type.keyword` instead. This change apply to any field of `text` type and has a sub-field of type `keyword` available (assuming the name of this field is `keyword`). So change as below:

```
'sort' => [
    ["type.keyword"=>["order"=>"asc"]],
    ["sr"=>["order"=>"asc"]],
    ["propLabels"=>["order"=>"asc"]],
    ["value"=>["order"=>"asc"]]
]
```

### Update : Index creation and query to get desired output

Create the index as below:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "start_with_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_edge_ngram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ngramed": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use the query below to get the desired result:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Ram",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Ram",
            "fields": [
              "name.ngramed"
            ],
            "analyzer": "start_with_analyzer",
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

In the above the query with boost value 5 increases the score for those documents where `Ram` is present in `name`. The other query with boost 2 further increases the score for the documents where `name` starts with `Ram`.

Sample O/P:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 2.0137746,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Ram Reddy"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.4384104,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Joy Ram Das"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.5753642,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Ramesh Singh"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @shivank01 Can you add the complete query. Use `echo json_encode($body);`.

Comment: Sorry, that was somehow deleted from database. But the order is still same as before. I have add the complete query in question.

Comment: "Joy ram reddy" is still showing before "Ram reddy".

Comment: That might be because of the sorting you have specified in the query. Score is no more considered

Comment: It is still not showing the desired result even after removing the sorting part.

Comment: Added the required changes in index creation and the query to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. It's working fine now. but it is not showing "ramesh singh".

Comment: It should. I tested for it. You need to reindex you data as well.

Comment: I have reindexed. It is showing ramesh when I give "ram*". else it is not giving

Comment: In what case it is not showing. Edge n gram has min val 3. So it will require at least first 3 characters to get a match. You can adjust this value to your needs

Comment: Please cross check you have not missed something. Try deleting index, recreating as above and the search. I have recheck my answer and added the sample o/p as well.

Comment: I have checked and also reindexed but the result is same. I have edited the code in the question as per your answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194214/discussion-between-nishant-saini-and-shivank01).