# Match query not return exacth match as first row

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch, with field `fullName` :

1. John Doe Doe
2. John Doe
3. Eric John Doe

When I do a match query against `fullName`, with this query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "fullName": {
                            "query": "John Doe",
                            "operator": "AND",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to get `John Doe` (exact match) as first result.
Instead, the returned value is in this sequence:

1. John Doe Doe
2. Eric John Doe
3. John Doe

Where the exact match is on the lowest result.

What should I do to put the exact match into first result?
I cannot use `term` query since I still need a fuzzy match on `fullName`

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532813/correct-sorting-for-exact-matches-and-beginning-with-prefix-in-elasticsearch/54538015#54538015) might help you.

Comment: @NishantSaini The suggested answer provide very valuable information but it does not handle duplicated terms. "John Doe" would still be after "John Doe Doe".

Answer (score 1):

The wrong order is due to 2 distinct problems.

## Fix the order for the second and third document

The wrong order between the second and the third documents is probably due to sharding. If you use a single shard you would get the following order:

- John Doe Doe
- John Doe
- Eric John Doe

You can read [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html#_relevancy_looks_wrong) wich explain why. However, if you have many document in each shard you should not have this problem. If you want to ensure that the statistics are **always** correct you can use [`_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch) in your search query parameters.

## Fix the order for the first and second document

This is a bit more tricky. The default **elasticsearch similarity** (i.e., BM25) will **increase the score if a term occurs multiple time**. In your case "Doe" appears twice and consequently its score is higher. To change this behavior you must use a [custom similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html).

You have two solutions:

- Write a [scripted similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity) based on an existing similarity to discard the importance of repeated terms
- Configure the default BM25 similarity to reduce the importance of repeated terms

To create a custom similarity on an existing index you must:

- [close the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html)
- add a similarity using the `_settings` endpoint.
- reopen the index

You can also add the similarity when you create the index. In the example, I will always create a new index.

To **use a similarity**, you can either set it as [default similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#default-base) or create subfields using specifically the similarity. Please note that changing the default similarity will impact **all your queries in the index**. In your case, I think it is better to create subfields.

### Solution 1: Create a scripted similarity

Using this solution, you will use a scripted similarity discarding the impact of duplicated terms. This script is based on TFIDF.

```
PUT /<INDEX>
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "similarity": {
                "scripted_tfidf": {
                    "type": "scripted",
                    "script": {
                        "source": "return query.boost * (Math.log((field.docCount+1.0)/(term.docFreq+1.0)) + 1.0) / Math.sqrt(doc.length);"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "fullName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "custom_similarity": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "similarity": "scripted_tfidf"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Comments

- TFIDF is a deprecated similarity, however it is deprecated due to its behavior with duplicated terms. Since we remove the impact of duplicated terms, it is fine.
- Because duplicated terms are completely discarded, using this solution the exact match will always be first, but "John Doe Doe" and "Eric John Doe" will have the same score.

### Solution 2: Configure BM25 similarity

You can change the similarity behavior by configuring the [BM25 similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#bm25). It has 2 parameters `k1` and `b`.

- `k1`: Defines the importance given to repeated terms. You want to lower this value;
- `b`: Defines the importance given to the number of terms. You want to increase this value.

```
PUT /<INDEX>
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "similarity": {
                "bm_25_custom": {
                    "type": "BM25",

                    // Update k1 and b values for bm25
                    "k1": "0.1",     
                    "b": "1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "fullName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {

                    // Add a subfield using the similarity defined previously
                    "custom_similarity": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "similarity": "bm_25_custom"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Comments

- If you set `k1 = 0`, both the duplicated terms and the number of terms will be discarded when you compute the score. Your first and second documents will have the same score and the order will be random.