# Elastic Search text search not scoring more for exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have created below mapping in ES index :

```
{
  "field_to_search": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And using below query to get the data :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field_to_search": {
              "query": "is this test?",
              "boost": 10,
              "fuzziness": "2",
              "prefix_length": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

Getting results :

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_id": "2551",
  "_score": 70.02259,
  "_source": {
    "id": "2551",
    "field_to_search": "is this test value?",
  }
}, 
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_id": "2545",
  "_score":  61.861847,
  "_source": {
    "id": "2545",
    "field_to_search": "is this test?",
  }
},
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_id": "2355",
  "_score":  50.987878,
  "_source": {
    "id": "2355",
    "field_to_search": "is this test performance value?",
  }
}
```

Expected : is this test? doc on top

Here I'm not getting exact match on top. Score for exact match is less than the fuzzy match. Can someone please help here?

I have tried fuzzy query with min boost as well but didn't worked.

Comment: According to the mapping datatype of `field_to_search` is `object`, whereas result shows that `field_to_search` is of type `text`. This is not possible. Are you sure the mapping is correct?

Comment: Yes. I have added mapping for that field as below as well :
"field_to_Search": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },

Comment: Ok, I updated the mapping in question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532813/correct-sorting-for-exact-matches-and-beginning-with-prefix-in-elasticsearch/54538015#54538015) answer might be helpful.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant - I have already tried that but not worked for me.

Comment: All the documents that you added as results have same id. Are these the output for executing the query three separate times? Can you add documents that you indexed, the complete query dsl that you used to index them?

Comment: No.  Documents in o/p are different. and getting this output in single execution. What I noticed here is - if there are some suffixes to the given string then those results appearing in top with more score. can you tell me how to avoid that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212140/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-nishant-and-shweta-chinchore).

Answer (score 0):

Have you reindexed your data after each mapping update?

`&explain=true` will provide more scoring insight.

Comment: Yes, I did re-indexing of my data after each mapping update. Also I tried with explain=true but not worked for me. I'm using ES 5.4.2. Is version may cause issue?